# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with NVIDIA Quadro K1100M

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

I use Ubuntu for testing WiFi networking hardware at my job.  I recently had to replace the laptop that I was using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with a new laptop.  It is an HP laptop with the NVIDIA Quadro K1100M on a 32 bit OS.  It took me much tweaking to get it to work properly, but I was able to do it with installing the proper drivers and modules.  The problem is that each time I get a Linux Kernel update, it causes a problem that I believe is related to XServer and the NVIDIA graphics card.  I installed the closed source drivers from NVIDIA, and ran the Xserver config tool from NVIDIA (/usr/bin/nvidia-xconfig).  That seemed to work with the original install, and the first update that I received.  With the last linux image update (linux-image-3.16.0-38-generic), it once again crashed my system.  I am forced to use the grub menu to boot the previous version, as I cannot seem to fix it this time.

What can I do to prevent future kernel updates from causing this problem?  I had previously tried making the xorg.conf file immutable, thinking if I prevented the configuration from being overwritten it would stop this from happening, but that did nothing.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by a wrong way of installing Nvidia drivers. You probably downloaded a .run file form Nvidia site. In this case the driver is not properly installed and will need to be re-installed every time you update kernel.

The correct way of installing Nvidia drivers in Ubuntu is to go to System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers.
Alternative way is to use apt-get.

But if you already installed drivers from a .run file, then you need to uninstall them first by running that file again with "--uninstall" parameter.

Comment: By george that did it.  Thank you very much.  I have been using Ubuntu for over 4 years now (mostly command line though), and never knew that existed!  I was able to boot to the latest image after uninstalling the driver using the .run file, and re-installing through the system settings.  Awesome Sauce!!!

Comment: @RodneyH just a quick thought... please accept the answer since it is correct